# Pasting text into keyring access prompt

Tags: gnupg, clipboard

I have quite a few keys I manage with Seahorse, and the passwords to them are quite complex, and kept in a safe method from which I must paste them(they are 64 characters). When I attempt to use these keys(sign, encrypt, etc), I am prompted with the agent to enter the key password. However, this agent refuses to accept pasted data(the password), and due to my having many keys, entering the passwords painstakingly(even just for the first time to save it to the keyring) is prohibitively difficult. Is there a workaround that will allow pasting into this window?

Comment: If you paste the same thing into a terminal or text editor, do you have extra whitespace or a new line at the beginning or the end?

Comment: @dobey No, it is just text without whitespace. It is of the format(while this is not my real password): `DHMpuCiUgfgL3P7GDXdMCPkV3AjtntZgalxhgGvp2mDRjEhZMH3xY9VURuVHwODu`, and is accepted hand-typed. Also, there is no right-click menu in the textbox, which I find odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is cumbersome, one may paste the password into another (secure) program, such as `gedit`, and then after selecting the entire password, dragging it into the errant box. This actually has the weird effect of, for the current session, allowing pasting via keyboard shortcut into the errant window.